# Webpack CLI does not work in project

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I have followed the instructions to a [React tutorial](https://github.com/ziad-saab/react-pizza-project). I installed NPM using `npm install` in the terminal and was able to start the node server. The issue is I am unable to run Webpack to view updates in my browser.

When I type `webpack --watch` as instructed, the terminal gives the error message: `'webpack' not found`, but Webpack has been installed in `node_modules`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must know the difference of installing locally and globally, and when to do so. Per the [NPM Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally):

> **If you want to use it as a command line tool, something like the grunt CLI, then you want to install it globally**. On the other hand, if you want to depend on the package from your own module using something like Node's `require`, then you want to install locally. (emphasis mine)

Thus, you must install Webpack globally to use its CLI (command line interface). Do:

```
npm install webpack -g
```

That way, it's globally installed and you can run Webpack through the command line with the `webpack` command. If you don't install it globally, you can still use the path to the locally installed module and execute as such:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch
```

This might be a bit inconvenient and you should opt for the global install. See [the Webpack Documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html) for more details.

Comment: I installed webpack globally but it's still not working.

Comment: @user3574939 You said you were running from terminal and it wasn't working? Does it say "command webpack not found" or similar? Did you try the second option?